# Why am i getting the error message "package 'owncloud' has no installation candidate?"

Tags: server, apt, package-management, software-installation

I am attempting to install Owncloud to Ubuntu server 14.10.  I am using the code:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/community/xUbuntu_14.10/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install owncloud
```

From the [website](http://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:community&package=owncloud)

Please tell me how I can fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The package exists. Check the `list` file, it should look like this;:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/community/xUbuntu_14.10/ /
```

And don't forget to add the public key:

```
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:community/xUbuntu_14.10/Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
```

After that

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install owncloud
```

---

*Sample output on my system*

```
$ sudo apt-get install owncloud
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils exim4 exim4-base exim4-config exim4-daemon-light
  heirloom-mailx libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap
  libhtml-template-perl liblua5.1-0 libmcrypt4 libpq5 libterm-readkey-perl mysql-client-5.6
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server-core-5.6 owncloud-3rdparty owncloud-app-activity
  owncloud-app-external owncloud-app-files owncloud-app-files-encryption
  owncloud-app-files-external owncloud-app-files-locking owncloud-app-files-pdfviewer
  owncloud-app-files-sharing owncloud-app-files-texteditor owncloud-app-files-trashbin
  owncloud-app-files-versions owncloud-app-files-videoviewer owncloud-app-firstrunwizard
  owncloud-app-gallery owncloud-app-provisioning-api owncloud-app-templateeditor
  owncloud-app-user-external owncloud-app-user-ldap owncloud-app-user-webdavauth
  owncloud-config-apache owncloud-server php-pear php-xml-parser php5 php5-cli php5-common
  php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php5-json php5-mcrypt php5-mysqlnd php5-pgsql php5-readline
  php5-sqlite
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom eximon4 exim4-doc-html exim4-doc-info
  spf-tools-perl swaks libipc-sharedcache-perl libmcrypt-dev mcrypt tinyca clamav clamav-daemon
  smbclient php5-imagick libav-tools ffmpeg php5-ldap php5-apcu php-apc php5-dev php5-user-cache
Recommended packages:
  mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils exim4 exim4-base exim4-config exim4-daemon-light
  heirloom-mailx libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap
  libhtml-template-perl liblua5.1-0 libmcrypt4 libpq5 libterm-readkey-perl mysql-client-5.6
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server-core-5.6 owncloud owncloud-3rdparty
  owncloud-app-activity owncloud-app-external owncloud-app-files owncloud-app-files-encryption
  owncloud-app-files-external owncloud-app-files-locking owncloud-app-files-pdfviewer
  owncloud-app-files-sharing owncloud-app-files-texteditor owncloud-app-files-trashbin
  owncloud-app-files-versions owncloud-app-files-videoviewer owncloud-app-firstrunwizard
  owncloud-app-gallery owncloud-app-provisioning-api owncloud-app-templateeditor
  owncloud-app-user-external owncloud-app-user-ldap owncloud-app-user-webdavauth
  owncloud-config-apache owncloud-server php-pear php-xml-parser php5 php5-cli php5-common
  php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php5-json php5-mcrypt php5-mysqlnd php5-pgsql php5-readline
  php5-sqlite
0 upgraded, 60 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 45.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 236 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: Very unusual to use an OpenSUSE package, but it works...  ;-)