# Owncloud has no installation cadidate, how do I fix?

Tags: 16.04, owncloud-server

I am trying to install Owncloud server on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 and have been following [these instructions from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-owncloud-on-ubuntu-16-04) and it has gone flawlessly up until the command

```
$ sudo apt-get install owncloud
```

and it returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package owncloud is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
    owncloud-files
```

So I tried running

```
$ sudo apt-get install owncloud-files
```

Which something installed, but it didn't do the installer as expected per the Digital Ocean instructions. I googled around and found [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639756/why-am-i-getting-the-error-message-package-owncloud-has-no-installation-candi) and did as A.B. said except I changed to my version of Ubuntu and nothing changed.

Where do I go from here?

EDIT

To be clear, I have done all of the steps leading up to the install of owncloud.

```
$ sudo curl https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -
[sudo] password for user: 
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  4502  100  4502    0     0   3847      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  3847
OK

$ echo 'deb https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list
deb https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04/ /

$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Ign:7 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04  InRelease
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Hit:10 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04  Release
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [60.3 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [644 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [57.6 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [49.6 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [80.0 kB]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [611 kB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [305 kB]
Ign:19 https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04  InRelease
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [213 kB]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [540 kB]
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [516 kB]
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [173 kB]
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [240 kB]
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,888 B]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,328 B]
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4,584 B]
Hit:28 https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04  Release
Fetched 3,809 kB in 1s (1,932 kB/s)                                           
Reading package lists... Done

$ sudo apt-get install owncloud
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package owncloud is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  owncloud-files

E: Package 'owncloud' has no installation candidate
```

That is everything that happens when I follow the steps, it still says there is no 'owncloud' installation candidate.

Comment: Redo Step #1 of those instructions. You didn't add the repository that you need.

Comment: @user535733 I updated the post, I just ran everything again and still get the same error.

Comment: After you change the sources, you must update your package database (`sudo apt update`). Once the package manager knows what is available from the new source, *then* you can download software from it.

Comment: @user535733 is sudo apt-get update different than sudo apt update? Either way I just ran sudo apt update again and still no luck.

Comment: 'still no luck' is too vague. *something* happened, or you got an error message when your ran `sudo apt update`. Were the new repos 'Hit'? Or 'Ign'? Or something else? We grok that you may not understand all the cryptic stuff on your screen, but we do understand it, and we need to know what it says.

Comment: @user535733 everything is in the above post. Copy/pasted exactly as the terminal spit it out after every command. As per the above post Hit 28 goes to the owncloud repo.  Above that ign 19 goes to owncloud as well. But exactly as I posted after the "EDIT" part is exactly what happens word for word.

Comment: Ah, thanks. 'Ign' means that apt did not fetch, for whatever reason, any list of software from that source. Until owncloud's repo starts working, you won't get any software from it. Owncloud's problem. Not a fault with apt nor with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you use Nextcloud instead. It is fully open source, faster and more secure. And has more features. Most of the Owncloud community moved to Nextcloud now.
Instructions for Nextcloud on Digital Ocean and Ubuntu can be found here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-nextcloud-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: hi i tried setting this up and upon trying to access the web it says page not found?

Answer (score 0):

As they describe it in the install instructions, you have to add a repository in order to install your package.
So, you can execute this commands in a terminal with copy & past:

```
sudo curl https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04/Release.key | sudo apt-key add - && echo 'deb https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list && sudo apt-get update
```

after this had been executed, you try to install it again `sudo apt-get install owncloud`

Comment: Clarified my post, I have done those but just re-ran all the commands to no avail. I also copy/pasted what you wrote and still got nothing. Thanks for your help!